# Bracket requirement on MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Why are brackets around the `COUNT` required in the below?

```
SELECT
    Measures.[Count] on COLUMNS,
    (
     Conference.Conference.members,
    {Division.Division.&North, Division.Division.&South}
  )
     on ROWS
FROM Avails
```

The query works removing the brackets on every word except for the `.[Count]` in the above. I thought brackets were only required if there's a space in the name?

Comment: Does the below help?

Answer (score 1):

They are needed cause count is a function. Try renaming it to count123 and use it without []